# is this P(X<Y | Y = y) = P(X<y) true

Tags: conditional-probability

Is this formula true? $P(X<Y | Y = y) = P(X<y)$

I am trying to solve this with conditional formula, but don't know how

$P(X<Y | Y= y) = \frac{P(X<Y, Y= y)}{P(Y=y)}  = \frac{P(X<y)}{P(Y=y)}. $

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: suppose it is independent, then P(X<Y,Y =y) = P(X<Y)P(Y=y) gives P(X<Y) which is still not P(X<y)